# Trying to find the top 5 and bottom 5 of this variable?

Tags: r

Okay, so I'm trying to find the top 5 counties for the variable "total_used". I was trying different stuff with the top_five data set compared to the bottom_five data set. My problem is that I'm trying to just print out the top/bottom five counties. But I keep getting repeats of counties, and I don't want repeats, I want 5 different ones. I don't know how to change it so that I don't get any repeats but also, I don't know how to get it to churn out 5 different ones.

```
top_five <- arrange(dataset, total_used) %>%
  select(County, na.rm = TRUE) 

print(top_five)

bottom_five <- arrange(dataset, desc(total_used)) %>%
  count = n(5) %>%
  select(County) 

print(bottom_five)
```

Comment: You are `select`ing the entire column 'County'.  I am guessin you need `slice_head(n = 5) or `slice_tail(n = 5)` or may be do a `distinct` in between.  Without a small reproducible example and expected output, it is hard to say.  May be `top_n(dataset, n = 5, wt = total_used)`

Answer (score 0):

As Akrun said, difficult to know without an example, some ideas though

```
dataset <- tibble(County= c("C1","C1", "C2","C2"), 
              total_used= c(1,5,6,4))

dataset %>% 
  group_by(County) %>% 
  filter(total_used == max(total_used)) %>% 
  head(5)

dataset %>% 
  group_by(County) %>% 
  filter(total_used == min(total_used)) %>% 
  head(5)

dataset %>% 
  arrange(total_used) %>% 
  group_by(County) %>% 
  slice_tail()
```